# Can not resolve R.id.toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm dipping my toes into Android Development by following along examples from [this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Android-Programming-with-Android-Studio-4th-Edition.productCd-1118705599.html). I am unable to get the example below to work, though. Instructions are: 1) New project named Dialog 2) Empty Activity 3) Paste/edit to look like the code below.

The message is that Studio can't resolve: **R.id.toolbar**, **R.id.fab**, **R.menu**, and **R.id.action_settings**.

I'm running Android Studio 3.1.3 on macOS High Sierra. My best guess is that that either the instructions are missing steps or since the book is ~2 years old Android Studio has changed behavior causing this example to break. I don't know enough about this development process to even know how to start to diagnose this.

In AndroidManifest.xml add this line to the activity block:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

And this is the only code file to change (DialogActivity.java) for the project:

```
package com.example.sample.dialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with an action",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dialog, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_dialog.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DialogActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for activity_dialog.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the id's in the `R.layout.activity_dialog` file. Android studio will output that message when the id that you are looking for is not found in the inflated layout.

**EDIT:**

You do not have a Toolbar declared in your XML file. When you want to search for a layout element to use in a Fragment or Activity, you use the id parameter you set in the XML file. If you forget to set the id or use the wrong id, it will tell you that the symbol cannot be resolved. There are too many items to add to your code, but follow the links below and you'll pick it up quickly enough. Let me know if you need more information. Also, [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android) is an excellent resource that I heavily relied on when I started learning Android development.

Look at [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar) for a tutorial for adding a toolbar to a layout file and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar) for more miscellaneous information.

Comment: This might be the issue. I added the activity_dialog.xml contents at the top. The book has not discussed what the the R object is and the example doesn't mention it at all. This is something that needs to be done by hand?

Comment: Yes. When you want to search for a layout element to use in a Fragment or Activity, you use the id parameter you set in the xml file. If you forget to set the id or use the wrong id, it will tell you that the symbol cannot be resolved.

Comment: Yep. Ok. Went to the books' website and the downloaded code has this file updated. I don't understand it, but I can see the references in it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I would highly recommend looking through a few [CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android) and [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html) tutorials. They focus on practical examples and explain things nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting those errors is because Java is looking for references in XML that have not been created. For example, it is looking for a reference called "R.id.fab" which was never created.

To fix this, you are going to have to go into the res folder and create the necessary files. Inside of the res  -> layout -> "activity_dialog.xml" file, you will have to create a FAB in order to get rid of that error. You can copy/paste this code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

Here, I create the necessary View in XML, and give it an id called fab so you can reference it in the java code. You will also need to create a menu folder and file, so to do that right click on the res folder, and go to "new Android Resource File". Set the file name to "menu" and the resource type should also be menu. Then when you hit "OK", you will see a new folder called menu, and inside of that a file called "menu.xml". 
Inside that "menu.xml" file, you're going to have to create your menu options with an id of "action_settings". You can do that by using the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="Settings"/>
</menu>
```

Lastly, you can create your toolbar by right clicking on the layout folder and selecting new layout resource file. You can name it 'toolbar', and set the root element to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. This will generate the appropriate code for you, and you can edit it however you'd like. After that go back into the "activity_dialog.xml" file and use this code:

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

This should get rid of all 4 errors

Answer (score 0):

You have not gotten a reference to the view from the xml.

Get the reference from the xml for example if have a button defined in xml with an id of myBtn i would get the reference as Button button = findViewById(R.id.myBtn).

Answer (score 0):

On the main menu, choose File. Invalidate Caches/Restart. The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches.